# How to set Virtualbox appliance as webdev portable sollution?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, web-development, appliance

I just want to set a a Virtualbox virtual appliance to make it portable. Meaning that I'll enable a network config which will not need to be changed when I am using my laptop in a different network. I want the virtual machine to have internet access to keep it updated and be able to always have direct access from host using, for example, the IP 10.0.2.100 even when I am in a 192.168.0.1 network. So the first virtual network adapter will have a static ip (10.0.2.100) and the second will receive it from the DHCP.
I don't know if 2 virtual adapters are needed or just one to accomplish that.

Is there already a solution for this situation?

Comment: Am I asking it in the wrong StackExchange site?